# JavaFX XYChart NumberAxis

Tags: javafx

I'm having problems with the y axis on a custom XYChart.  The y axis is a NumberAxis, and I set the tick label formatter to a custom formatter.  Auto-ranging is off.  When I change the upper bound of the chart and request an axis layout, the old labels remain on the chart.  With debug logging, I can see that the custom formatter methods are being invoked, and that they return the correct Strings, but the tick labels on the chart do not update.  The only ones that do update are the ones that were not on the axis before.  For example, if the range of the y axis was 0 to 3, and then I change the upper bound from 3 to 5, new labels with the correct values will show up at indices 4 and 5.  However, the labels for 0 through 3 do not update even though the custom formatter now returns different Strings for them.

I tried taking the custom formatter out of the equation and simply changed the tick label fill to another color when I changed the upper bound of the y axis, and I saw the same behavior (labels for pre-existing indices had the old color, and labels for new indices had the new color).  I hope I'm missing something obvious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Otherwise I may need to resort to recreating the chart whenever the y axis labels need to change.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, the tick labels themselves are basically immutable. Once a range is set, it only adds and removes ticks, but doesn't update them.  What I did to overcome this is to set the upper bound to the lower bound (effectively removing all ticks), and then setting the upper bound back to the range I wanted, so it would re-create the ticks.